Default location for config file in openconnect
I use openconnect for my work vpn.  I'm trying to locate the default location for the config file in openconnect. This does not seem to be documented on the (otherwise excellent) man page.
Enlightenment appreciated.
--  Saul

It doesn't have one. You can specify one or specify all the options at commandline - but if you run openconnect on its own it will simply output a help text.

OK; thanks.  --Saul
